# VB Script; Identifying file paths of more than 255 characters

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, filepath

I am currently trying to write a VB script in order to identify file paths that are too large (255+), in a large hierarchical network structure. These are usually truncated and end with a tilde (~). I need to get the file paths outputted onto a text file, so that someone can manually decide what to do with them. Scanning the whole server would be too large a job, and so I was hoping to be able to run the script on certain folders and their sub-folders.

I am quite comfortable with VB for access, but have never used VB Script to manipulate directories like this.

I'm using windows 7, and the directories could be server based.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post code or give details on what you have tried? What do you have at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

If your problematic paths ends with a `~`, you can use

```
dir /s /b x:\someFolder1 | findstr /e /c:"~" >  paths.txt
dir /s /b x:\someFolder2 | findstr /e /c:"~" >> paths.txt
....
```